# Find diff between three tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to find the difference between three tables, a, b, and c. I'd like to join all three, showing nulls where each table does not have records.

Each table has two columns that I would like to join on, lets say first and last name.

So far, this is what I'm doing.

```sql
Select * from a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b on 
  a.firstName = b.firstName AND a.lastname = b.lastname 
FULL OUTER JOIN c on 
  (c.firstName = a.firstName and c.lastName = a.LastNAME) OR 
  (c.firstName = b.firstName AND c.lastname = b.LastName)
```

I'm not confident that the logic in my output is correct. Is there a better way of doing this? In english, the first join joins A and B, including records in each table that don't exist in the other table. The second join joins A+B to C, joining C to either A or B if it matches.

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I believe your query does what you want.  You could add a where clause if you want to exclude matches `where a.firstName is null or b. firstName is null or c.firstName is null`.

Comment: @avery_larry yeah I think after testing, you're right. I do like Gordon's implementation though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want:

```
select firstname, lastname, sum(in_a), sum(in_b), sum(in_c)
from ((select firstname, lastname, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b, 0 as in_c
       from a
      ) union all
      (select firstname, lastname, 0 as in_a, 1 as in_b, 0 as in_c
       from b
      ) union all
      (select firstname, lastname, 0 as in_a, 0 as in_b, 1 as in_c
       from c
      )
     ) abc
group by firstname, lastname;
```

This should each `firstname`/`lastname` pair with information about how many times the pair is in each table.

I prefer the `union all`/`group by` approach for this over `left join` for several reasons:

1. Without the `using` clause, the `on` clause gets a bit tricky as you add more tables.
2. Minimal use of `coalesce()`.
3. Better handles duplicates *within* each table.
4. Handles `NULL` values for the keys.

Comment: Yeah, these results are a little more digestable that what I was doing. Thanks.